# Estimation of Translation in Salesforce

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, salesforcedx, translation, translation-workbench

Can anyone tell me if i want to translate the complete org into 10 different languages how much time will it take? Is there any elements in org that cannot be translated? If i am translating the org for the first time and using translation workbench then will it take more time? How to edit the .stf files ? Because if i am using excel or word then i am getting errors.

Please help me regarding all this questions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone tell me if i want to translate the complete org into 10 different languages how much time will it take?

It may take a few hours or a few weeks (or even longer). There's no way we could tell you how long it would take without knowing more about your org. Your best bet would be to download the translation files to get an estimate.

> Is there any elemnts in org that cannot be translated?

As far as the front end user interface, you can [translate](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=translatable_customizations.htm&type=5) most elements. I don't know if there's something you have in mind that's not translatable, but the list of things you can translate should pretty much cover anything you'd *want* to translate.

> If i am translating the org for the first time and using translation workbench then will it take more time?

It should take approximately the same amount of time overall, though the stf files will probably be faster in the long run if you have many elements.

> How to edit the stf files ?

Preferably, use a translation software package designed for the purpose of editing stf files. Note that Microsoft Excel can cause errors in the file, and Microsoft Word is also likely to cause problems in the file; you may be required to open the file in a text editor to fix these problems. You might try [OmegaT](https://omegat.org/) or another translation software suite (salesforce.com mentions SDL Trados).

Comment: Hey thanks.. @sfdcfox .. got my answers clearly.. thnx fr the info

Comment: Hey can u help me with a template of a translated stf file that i can refer to follow the best practise